# ¿Como prohibir caracteres especiales en el registro de usuario?

Tags: php

Soy novato en esto y no tengo mucha idea, el codigo figura asi

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('usuario', array('label' => 'El nombre de tu Equipo','class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Por ejemplo: Pepe F.C')); ?>
    </div><!-- .form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
    </div><!-- .form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('confirmar_password', array('type'=>'password','class' => 'form-control')); ?>
    </div><!-- .form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('fecha_nacimiento', array('class' => 'form-control fecha', 'type' => 'text')); ?>
    </div><!-- .form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Tuemail@dominio.com')); ?>
    </div><!-- .form-group -->
    <div class="form-group" style="float:right;">
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Registrarse', array('class' => 'btn btn-large btn-primary')); ?>
    </div><!-- .form-group -->
    </fieldset>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Mi pregunta es: ¿que caracteres especiales quieres prohibir? Podrías probar [^\u0021-\u002F] que son estos caracteres: `! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . /`

Answer (score 2):

En lugar de prohibir carácteres especiales (que son muchos) podes intentar delimitando solo aquellos que sí aceptas, por ejemplo, digitos y letras en mayusculas y minúsculas, por ejemplo:

```
$regexp = '/^[a-z0-9]+$/i';
$entrada = 'user_name';

$resultado = preg_match($regexp, $entrada);
if(!$resultado) {
  echo 'entrada incorrecta: ' . $entrada . PHP_EOL;
}

$entrada = 'userName';
$resultado = preg_match($regexp, $entrada);
if($resultado) {
  echo 'entrada correcta: ' . $entrada . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yo lo hago con javascript, desde el propio formulario se limita los caracteres especiales

```js
 $('.input-number-line').on('input', function () { 
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9-]/g,'');
    });
     $('.input-number-guion-abajo').on('input', function () { 
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9_]/g,'');
    });
    $('.input-number').on('input', function () { 
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    });
    
     $('.texto').on('input', function () { 
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA.():/,@ _-]/g,'');
    });
    $('.fuente').on('input', function () { 
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.()/::,@ _-]/g,'');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>numeros </p>
<input autofocus="" class="form-control input-number" id="coordenaday_mass" maxlength="45" required="required" type="text">
<p>numeros y linea 9-0 y ____</p>
<input autofocus="" class="form-control input-number-guion-abajo" id="coordenaday_mass" maxlength="45" required="required" type="text">
<p>numeros y linea 9-0  ----- </p>
<input autofocus="" class="form-control input-number-line" id="coordenaday_mass" maxlength="45" required="required" type="text">

<p>solo texto   ----- </p>
<input autofocus="" class="form-control texto" id="coordenaday_mass" maxlength="45" required="required" type="text">

<p> texto, numero y tilde   ----- </p>
<input autofocus="" class="form-control fuente" id="coordenaday_mass" maxlength="45" required="required" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede usar `preg_replace` para eliminar caracteres especiales de la entrada, como este:

`preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', input('usuario', array('label' => 'El nombre de tu Equipo','class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Por ejemplo: Pepe F.C'))`

También puede usar `preg_match` para verificar si una entrada tiene un carácter especial, y luego manejarlo como desee, como este:
`if(!preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z\d]/', $string)){//enviar}`

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que PHP es un lenguaje que se ejecuta en el servidor, una vez que el usuario quiera llenar los campos PHP ya no tendra jurisdicción sobre lo que pasa, hasta que el formulario sea enviado una vez más al servidor. En el navegador lo que puedes hacer para evitar que ingresen caracteres que no permites es agregar un evento de JavaScript el cual si tiene jurisdiccion de lo que pasa mientras el usuario interactua con tu página

```
$("#usuario").on('keypress', function (event) {
        let caracteresPermitidos = /[a-z0-9]/i;
        let code = event.which;
        let keyPress = String.fromCharCode(code);
        if (keyPress.search(code) < 0) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return;
        }
    });
```

Esto hará que solo ingrese caracteres que sean letras (mayuscula o minuscula) o numeros. Pero adicionalemente debes hacer la validacion del lado del servidor como lo indican los otros compañeros

Answer (score 0):

Mira, yo uso dicha validación del lado de Js, pero por si alguna razón la validación falla en Js, en PHP elimino esos caracteres que no me convienen con el método `str_replace`, te dejo un ejemplo de cómo yo lo hago desde **PHP**:

Primero, armo un array con todos los caracteres que no quiero que pasen:

```
$contenido = "Eüste es el conßtenidöo aÅl ¥cual eliüminaré carÅactere£s raro¥s";

$caracteresNoPermitidos = array("£","¥","è","ù","ì","ò","Ç","Ø","ø","Å","å","Æ","æ","ß","¤","¡","ä","ö","ü","à","Ü","Ö","Ä");
```

Después, simplemente elimino estos caracteres al contenido que recibiré:

```
$contenido = str_replace($caracteresNoPermitidos,'',$contenido);

echo $contenido;

//Al final retornará esto: Este es el contenido al cual eliminaré caracteres raros
```

Ahora, si lo necesitas con **JS**, te dejo un ejemplo con el cual bloqueo el ingreso de los caracteres que no necesito en algún campo de mi formulario:

En este caso bloqueamos los caracteres: ***!"#%&'()*+,-./***

```js
//Asociamos evento 'keypress', el cual ejecuta una función al momento se presionar o pulsar cualquier tecla
$('.js-campo').on('keypress', (e) => {
  //Obtenemos el código ASCII de la tecla pulsada
  let teclaPulsada = e.charCode;
  
  //Validamos el rango en el que se encuentran los caracteres No permitidos
  if (teclaPulsada >= 32 && teclaPulsada < 48) {
    //Con return false, bloqueamos el ingreso de estos caracteres
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="js-campo">
```

Aquí te dejo el [enlace (ASCII)](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/), donde encontrarás todos los códigos internos de cada tecla del teclado, donde aquí podras personalizar tu validación bloqueando o no el caracter que necesites, simplemente comparando `teclaPulsada == codigoCaracterPorBloquear`